# Problema con consulta UPDATE - MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, estoy haciendo un curso online que esta algo desactualizado, y me están surgiendo algunos problemas. Estoy intentando editar los datos de una web ficticia de autobuses mediante un formulario, pero tengo un problema. Os adjunto el código:

Desde una página se pueden ver todos los autobuses, y esto funciona perfectamente. Cada autobús tiene un botón de "editar", que lleva a un formulario para cambiar los datos. Este es el formulario en PHP:

```
<?php

include("funciones.php");    

if (isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id = $_GET["id"];
}

$resultado = cargarAutobusEditar($id);

$nombre = $resultado[0];
$color = $resultado[1];
$capacidad =$resultado[2];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Editar Autobús</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
        </h1>
        <h2>Editar Autobús</h2>
    </header>

    <form action="funciones.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $id ?>" />

        <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>" id="Nombre" />

        <label for="Color">Color</label>
        <input type="text" name="Color" value="<?php echo $color ?>" id="Color" />

        <label for="Capacidad">Capacidad</label>
        <input type="text" name="Capacidad" value="<?php echo $capacidad ?>" id="Capacidad" />

        <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Guardar" class="boton_editar"/>
        <a href="funciones.php?borrar=<?php echo $id ?>" class="borrar">Eliminar</a>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </form>

    <article id="ver_autobuses">
        <img src="images/autobus.png" alt="Imagen autobús" />
    </article>

</body>

</html>
```

En este formulario se recogen los datos de cada autobús gracias a la función cargarAutobusEditar($id), que es la siguiente:

```
function cargarAutobusEditar($id){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM autobuses WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'";

    $valor = conexionBD($consulta);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($valor))
    {
        $nombre = $row["Nombre"];
        $color = $row["Color"];
        $capacidad = $row["Capacidad"];
    }

    $resultado = Array($nombre, $color, $capacidad);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Esto funciona correctamente, se muestran en pantalla, en cada input del formulario, los datos del autobús correspondiente. El problema ocurre cuando voy a editar, pues cambio los datos y al hacer click en el botón editar se llama a esta función:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["editar"]))
{
    editarAutobus();
}

function editarAutobus(){
    $id = $_POST['ID'];
    $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $color = $_POST['Color'];
    $capacidad = $_POST['Capacidad'];
    $consulta = "UPDATE autobuses SET Nombre='" . $nombre . "', Color='" . $color. "', Capacidad='" . $capacidad . "' WHERE ID='" .$id . "'";

    conexionBD($consulta);
    header('Location:editar_autobuses.php?id='.$id);
}

?>
```

Al darle al botón para guardar los cambios y llamar a esta función, los campos del formulario se muestran vacíos...

Tengo otro script para dar de alta autobuses, pasando la consulta de MySQL mediante el mismo proceso, y funciona correctamente, por lo que entiendo que la conexión con la base de datos funciona correctamente. De todas formas, dejo las funciones:

```
function conexionBD($consulta){
    $dbLocal = new DBMySql("localhost", "root", "", "bus", 3306);
    $valor = $dbLocal->setQuery($consulta);
    return $valor;
}


<?php

class DBMySql extends BaseDeDatos
{
    protected $conexion;

    public function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $password, $db, $puerto = 3306){

        parent::__construct($servidor, $usuario, $password, $db, $puerto, "mysql");

        $this->conexion = mysqli_connect($this->servidor . ":" . $this->puerto, $this->usuario, $this->password);

        mysqli_select_db($this->conexion, $this->db);
    }

    public function setQuery($query){
        //$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexion, $query);
        return $this->idConsulta = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);
    }

?>
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar fallando?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

---

EDITADO:

Vale, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, intentando adaptar el script que ya tenía escrito, he utilizado los enlaces que me adjuntas y he editado esta parte del código:

```
function conexionBD($consulta){
    //$dbLocal = new DBMySql("localhost", "root", "", "bus", 3306);
    //$valor = $dbLocal->setQuery($consulta);
    $mipdo=new DbPDO();
    $valor = $mipdo->query($consulta);
    return $valor;
}
```

Con esto accedo al objeto creado que me has pasado, y consigo que cualquier consulta se pase mediante ese método. Por ahora no voy a utilizar el bind_params porque quiero que simplemente funcione, luego le añadiré como se indica. El problema es que algunas funciones han dejado de funcionar, supongo que porque utilizaba el "estilo de procedimientos" y no el "orientado a objetos". El error que se me muestra al utilizar esta función:

```
function verAutobuses(){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM autobuses";
    $valor = conexionBD($consulta);
    $resultado ="";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($valor))
    {
        $resultado .= "<h3>Nombre: <span>" . $row["Nombre"] . "<span><a href='editar_autobuses.php?id=" . $row["ID"] . "' class='editar'><img src='images/editar.png'></a></h3>";
        $resultado .= "<h4>Color: <span>" . $row["Color"] . "</span></h4>";
        $resultado .= "<h4>Capacidad: <span>" . $row["Capacidad"] . "</span></h4>";
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```

Y el error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\funciones.php on line 72

He estado mirando la documentación, y pensaba que al cambiar al estilo orientado a objetos debería escribir algo así:

```
function verAutobuses(){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM autobuses";
    $valor = conexionBD($consulta);
    $resultado ="";

    while ($row = $valor->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $resultado .= "<h3>Nombre: <span>" . $row["Nombre"] . "<span><a href='editar_autobuses.php?id=" . $row["ID"] . "' class='editar'><img src='images/editar.png'></a></h3>";
        $resultado .= "<h4>Color: <span>" . $row["Color"] . "</span></h4>";
        $resultado .= "<h4>Capacidad: <span>" . $row["Capacidad"] . "</span></h4>";
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```

Pero me devuelve este error, que no lo comprendo la verdad:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
>   on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\funciones.php:70 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\ver_autobuses.php(4): verAutobuses() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso\funciones.php on line 70

Muchas gracias por tus respuestas, las valoro mucho teniendo en cuenta que estoy empezando y esto me parece un mundo imposible.

Comment: Bueno... ya le he visto al menos tres faltas graves a lo que te *enseña* tu curso. Primero, te enseña a crear código vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Segundo, te enseña a crear código *mudo* en algunos puntos. Tercero (tiene que ver con lo segundo), te enseña a crear código *independiente*, que podría hacer lo que quiere cuando las cosas no salen como pensaba el programador. Por ejemplo, tú lanzas un `UPDATE`,  pero ese `UPDATE` puede fallar por varios motivos y tú deberías controlar todos los posibles fallos antes de redireccionar.

Comment: **[Aquí te dejo un ejemplo simple de `UPDATE`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uu3z-gdy9)** aplicando las tres normas antes mencionadas. Lo puedes probar pulsando `Run-F9`.

Comment: Por ejemplo aquí: `return $this->idConsulta = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $query);` estás retornando una propiedad que no existe en tu clase: `idConsulta`. Si te interesa, puedes [implementar esta clase, usando PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO). Es mucho más fácil de manejar y más completa y PDO tiene varias ventajas con respecto a mysqli. Luego podrás adaptarla a tus necesidades si lo desearas.

Comment: Además de la inyección SQL como bien indica @A.Cedano, este código también es vulnerable a ataques de XSS.

Comment: Me parece que el error por lo de PDO es que no es PDO nativo sino una clase implementada, por lo que para iterar sobre los elementos tendrías que hacer un foreach ya que ya te lo trae como arreglo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje indica que estás recibiendo ya un array. Si has usado la clase PDO de Github, esa clase devuelve por defecto un array asociativo con los datos.

Entonces:

```
function verAutobuses(){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM autobuses";
    $valor = conexionBD($consulta);
    $resultado ="";

    foreach ($valor as $row)
    {
        $resultado .= "<h3>Nombre: <span>" . $row["Nombre"] . "<span><a href='editar_autobuses.php?id=" . $row["ID"] . "' class='editar'><img src='images/editar.png'></a></h3>";
        $resultado .= "<h4>Color: <span>" . $row["Color"] . "</span></h4>";
        $resultado .= "<h4>Capacidad: <span>" . $row["Capacidad"] . "</span></h4>";
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```